# MySQL doesnt run on OSX after intall -- Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, osx-yosemite

I have a fresh OSX (Yosemite) installation i installed mysql using the following command

```
brew install mysql
```

Post installation it asked me to run the following command

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

After closing the iTerm and restarting when i try to access MySQL i get the following error

```
➜  ~  mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Did you already install `mysql-server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just need to start/restart mysql now.

Try

> mysql.server restart